# Extracting PDF thumbnails

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

We have a crossplatfrom (Windows, Linux, OS X, App Engine) Python application using reportlab to create PDF files, which include thumbnails (as seen in Acrobat Reader).

Is there a way to extract these thumbnails from the PDF file for document managment purposes (without rendering the pages themself with Ghostscript, MuPDF)?

Comment: Acrobat uses thumbnails when they are present, and generates them on the fly if not. Are you *sure* those thumbnails are saved inside your PDFs? (See [Adobe's PDF Reference 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), "8.2.3 Thumbnail Images" for how to check.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF doesn't contain thumbnails so there is nothing to extract. You will have to use some 3rd library like Ghostscript or MuPDF to rasterize each page.